# pyOpenSSL and ssh-keygen public key ssh-rsa 4096 not corresponding

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, rsa, pyopenssl, ssh-keygen

I created a key pair in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 through:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -b 4096 -C "cocchi.e89@gmail.com" -f /tmp/id_rsa
```

and I get the following public key:

```sh
cat /tmp/id_rsa

ssh-rsa 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 cocchi.e89@gmail.com
```

I try to generate the same public key using Python3.9 [pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/) but I get a different value:

```py
import OpenSSL

### 1. load PRIVATE KEY
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE='/tmp/id_rsa'
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD = '<my-secret-pwd>'

with open( PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, 'r') as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()

if PRIVATE_KEY.startswith('-----BEGIN '):
    PKEY = OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, PRIVATE_KEY, str.encode(PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD) )
else:
    PKEY = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(PRIVATE_KEY, str.encode(PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD)).get_privatekey()

### 2. get PUBLIC KEY
def pem_publickey(pkey):
    """ Format a public key as a PEM """
    bio = OpenSSL.crypto._new_mem_buf()
    OpenSSL._util.lib.PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, pkey._pkey)
    return OpenSSL.crypto._bio_to_string(bio)

PKEY.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 4096)
print(pem_publickey(PKEY))

b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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\n6H42T5nUOYgjHND3u9CheRkCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
```

Why is this happening? And how can I get to the same public key through [pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/)?

Comment: The answer to the first question is: The key formats differ. The key generated with ssh-keygen has the OpenSSH format and the key generated with pyOpenSSL has the X.509/SPKI format.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, it means it is impossible to convert them?

Comment: No, conversion is possible in principle, but _probably_ not with pyOpenSSL. At first glance, I don't see any indication in the [documentation](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api.html#module-OpenSSL) that the OpenSSH format is supported (but maybe I missed something). However, see the [note](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/) that recommends [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.PublicFormat), which also supports OpenSSH.